# Send url in php mail

Tags: url, phpmailer, php

I send a mp3 file download url which was taken from database and mailed to an user in php. 
When the links are triggerd to users,

- some links contain "!" marks and No hyperlink is generated.
- In some of the links, download.php file is downloaded.

Note:

When i print the message sent to mail, all the links are working fine. Only the problem in mail. i checked with Yahoo, and Gmail. Both have the same problem in same files.

`$this->_res['Song_Info']` contains the information of all mp3 files such as name , links and so on...

```
$emailto = "xxxx@yahoo.com";
$user_name = $this->_res['User_Info']['Name'];
$header = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$header.= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
$header.= "From:no-reply@example.com\r\n";
header.= "Bcc: yyy@gmail.com\r\n";
$message = "<table>";
$message = $message. "<tr><th align='left' colspan='3'>Dear user</th><tr>";
$message = $message."<tr><td colspan='3'>Here is the Download links</td></tr>";
$message = $message."<tr><td colspan='3'></td></tr>";
    foreach ($this->_res['Song_Info'] as $key => $value) {
        $message = $message."<tr><td colspan='3'><a href='www.example.com/download.php?dlink='.trim($value['Song_Url'])."'>".trim($value['Song_Name'])."<a></td></tr>";
    }
$message = $message."<tr><td colspan='3'></td></tr>";
$subject = "Download Links";
mail($emailto,$subject,$message,$header);
```

Thanks

Comment: What is an example value that could be contained in `$value['Song_Url']`?

Comment: $value['Song_Url'] = "http://www.example.com/download/02_Song_1.mp3";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change below two lines and then check

1) $ is missing

```
$header.= "Bcc: yyy@gmail.com\r\n";
```

2) String is broken

```
$message = $message.'<tr><td colspan="3"><a href="www.example.com/download.php?dlink='.trim($value['Song_Url']).'">'.trim($value['Song_Name']).'<a></td></tr>';
```

Also make sure when you run any songfile url with download.php?dlink=something it should download song. If it is not working check http://www.zubrag.com/scripts/download.php or [[http://www.finalwebsites.com/forums/topic/php-file-download](http://www.finalwebsites.com/forums/topic/php-file-download)

Comment: Sorry $header.= "Bcc: yyy@gmail.com\r\n", i made when i post in this site. but in my site , it is right.. Can u explain the 2 point

Comment: Most of the files are downloaded .. only few files not working

Comment: If you see $message string, there are mismatch of single and double quote. Even if you see color in above code you can see string is broken at trim function... Change your line with mine and then test.

Comment: You can see how php concatenation work at: http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/php/threads/369623/syntax-prpblems#post1588766

Comment: PHP Concatenation is correct one.. i checked that and also change suggested in that site. still i have the problem